# Product list row with dynamic height

Tags: jquery

Lets say that I have a product list with 3 products per line. Every product has a border but the height of border differs from product to product (because of different image height or more title lines etc). What I want is a function which will check the product which has the maximum height in the line. So, it will give to other products same height relating to maximum div height of every line.

So, in every line that function will work again relating to higher div of the line.

Let's play with that code:

CSS

```
.yagVmCategoryViewProductRow.row-fluid {
border: 1px solid #dedede;
width: 750px;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

.yagVmCategoryGridProductItem.span4 {
float: left;
width: 28.5%;
border: 1px solid #dedede;
padding: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="yagVmCategoryViewProductRow row-fluid">

    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItem span4">
        <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemSpacer">
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImg">               
                <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImgInner">                                  
                    <a class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImgLink" href="/index.php/el/proionta/energeia/zesto-nero/hliakos-thermosifonas-pyramis-120lt-epillektikou-syllekti-diplis-nergeias-detail">
                        <img class="featuredProductImage" src="http://polykatastima.net/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/ηλιακός-θερμοσίφωνας-120lt-επιλεκτικού-συλλέκτη-απλός_200x200.jpg" >
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductTitle">
                <h4 class="yagMobileHead4"><a href="/index.php/el/proionta/energeia/zesto-nero/hliakos-thermosifonas-pyramis-120lt-epillektikou-syllekti-diplis-nergeias-detail">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemPrice" id="productPrice266">
                <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBox">
                    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBoxRedInner">
                      <div class="PricesalesPrice"><span class="PricesalesPrice">736,00 €</span></div>                                              </div>

                    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBoxGreyInner">
                      <div class="PricebasePrice"><span class="PricebasePrice">1008,00 €</span></div>                                                   </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItem span4">
        <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemSpacer">
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImg">               
                <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImgInner">                                  
                    <a class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImgLink" href="/index.php/el/proionta/energeia/zesto-nero/hliakos-thermosifonas-pyramis-120lt-epillektikou-syllekti-diplis-nergeias-detail" >
                        <img class="featuredProductImage" src="http://polykatastima.net/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/free-standing-freezer-refrigerator-fsh-187-no-frost_n_200x200.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductTitle">
                <h4 class="yagMobileHead4">
                    <a href="/index.php/el/proionta/koyzina/neroxytes/pyragranite-caldera-86-51-1-3-4b-detail" >Pyragranite Caldera (86X51) 1 3/4B</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemPrice" id="productPrice266">
                <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBox">
                    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBoxRedInner">
                      <div class="PricesalesPrice"><span class="PricesalesPrice">736,00 €</span></div>                                              </div>

                    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBoxGreyInner">
                      <div class="PricebasePrice"><span class="PricebasePrice">1008,00 €</span></div>                                                   </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItem span4">
        <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemSpacer">
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImg">               
                <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImgInner">                                  
                    <a class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemImgLink" href="/index.php/el/proionta/energeia/zesto-nero/hliakos-thermosifonas-pyramis-120lt-epillektikou-syllekti-diplis-nergeias-detail">
                        <img class="featuredProductImage" src="http://polykatastima.net/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/caldera-(86x51)-1-3-4b_200x200.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductTitle">
                <h4 class="yagMobileHead4">
                    <a href="/index.php/el/proionta/koyzina/neroxytes/pyragranite-caldera-86-51-1-3-4b-detail" >Pyragranite Caldera (86X51) 1 3/4B</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProductItemPrice" id="productPrice266">
                <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBox">
                    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBoxRedInner">
                      <div class="PricesalesPrice" style="display : block;"><span class="PricesalesPrice">736,00 €</span></div>                                             </div>

                    <div class="yagVmCategoryGridProdPriceBoxGreyInner">
                      <div class="PricebasePrice" style="display : block;"><span class="PricebasePrice">1008,00 €</span></div>                                                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

UPDATED
http://jsfiddle.net/k30kveje/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ram Sharma's answer is correct. I made a minor adjustment. Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bcwd1b89/1/)

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div.row-fluid").each(function(){
            var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(this).find("div.yagVmCategoryGridProductItem").map(function ()
        {
            return $(this).height();
        }).get());

        $(this).find("div.yagVmCategoryGridProductItem").css("height", maxHeight);
    });



});
```

Comment: @ArinCool Thanks to complete it, I was in call with client. You completed the remaining answer +1 for that :)

Comment: it works. But I have a problem on mozzila. It works fine to my monitor. But in a monitor with higher resolution has problem take a look here  http://polykatastima.net/index.php/?index.php&mobile=phone

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("div.yagVmCategoryGridProductItem").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
```

You can also try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

   $('.yagVmCategoryGridProductItem').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.yagVmCategoryGridProductItem').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });
```

Comment: it works now. But I have a problem on mozzila. It works fine to my monitor. But in a monitor with higher resolution has problem take a look here  http://polykatastima.net/index.php/?index.php&mobile=phone